# AngularJS Change a single scope item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A little difficult to explain, 
we have worked through this sample

```
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope
```

but its not quite matching what we are trying to achieve.

we have built a controller which simply sets myData

```
  ClinicalNotesCtrl.controller('notesController', function notesController($scope, $http, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.myData = { name: "Moroni", age: 50, result: "Sodium" };

    $scope.changename = function (h) {
        h.name = "Simon";
        h.age = "34";
        h.result = "This is a test";

    }

    });
```

Below is the directive called kid. This just simply prints out the value

```
  Results.directive("kid", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
         // scope: { myValue: '=simon' },
       // scope:{},
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="myData.name">{{myData.name}}' // '<div>{{$scope.timelineactivitydata}}</div>',

    };
    });
```

and finally this is the HTML page,

```
  <kid simon="myData"></kid>
        <label ng-click="changename(myData)">Change Name</label>
<kid simon="myData"></kid>
        <label ng-click="changename(myData)">Change Name</label>
<kid simon="myData"></kid>
        <label ng-click="changename(myData)">Change Name</label>
```

What we are trying to achieve is to somehow relate a particular label to a kid directive, so that when clicking on the label, only the related kid will change its name, rather than all of them.

Hope that makes sense,

As requested in the comments, 
please see the plunker :-

plnkr.co/edit/3NMBNTrLT29EIFNo9lbA?p=preview

Comment: Have you got more than one item in `myData`? Are you displaying list of items or just an single item?

Comment: in our real life sample, the scope will not actually be populated until the button is clicked,  so in theory, myData will be just a single item

Comment: you paramaters 'h' is a local variable, you have to make the changes in the scope

Comment: '$scope.myData.name = "simon"' for example

Comment: this is simply still going to print out "simon" within all the kids. We're looking for a way to actually relate the label to the directive, so that only 1 kid directive will change the scope.

Comment: @Simon Could you reproduce this in fiddle?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/3NMBNTrLT29EIFNo9lbA?p=preview

Comment: It's the same object and same property - you'd have to make a copy of the object and go from there - or use `ng-repeat` and change the name on the new scope created from thart.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a solution here but I am not sure if it solves anything for you.

JS code

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('notesController', function notesController($scope, $http) {

```
$scope.myData = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50, result: "Sodium" },
                 { name: "Naomi", age: 50, result: "Sodium" },
                 { name: "Rambo", age: 50, result: "Sodium" }
];

$scope.changename = function (h) {
    h.name = "Simon";
    h.age = "34";
    h.result = "This is a test";
};

})
.directive("kid", function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope:{
        myData:"=simon",
        changed:"&change"
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="myData.name"/><span>'
                +'{{myData.name}}</span><label ' 
                +'ng-click="changed({\'data\':myData});">'
                +'Change Name</label><br/>'
};
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >
    <div ng-controller="notesController" >
         <kid ng-repeat="data in myData" simon="data" change="changename(data)">
         </kid>
    </div>
</div>
```